# Why does creating a virtual table require OPEN_READWRITE mode?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a SQLite database opened in `READ_ONLY` mode:

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.READ_ONLY);
```

and I am creating a virtual table like this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE fts_table USING fts3 (name, definition)");
```

However, this gives the error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database (code 8)
```

If I use `OPEN_READWRITE` mode then the operation succeeds.

Why is creating a virtual table requiring the `OPEN_READWRITE` mode? I thought that the virtual table is "virtual", meaning that the table is not written to the database on disk?

If it is requiring `OPEN_READWRITE` mode to create a virtual table then where is this table written to? Is it to the same database file, or to a separate temporary database file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Virtual tables`](https://sqlite.org/vtab.html) don't need physical tables on disk, but the [`full text search`](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) (FTS) module does for the shadow tables it creates.

**Shadow Tables**

> For each FTS virtual table in a database, three to five real (non-virtual) tables are created to store the underlying data. These real tables are called "shadow tables". The real tables are named `"%_content"`, `"%_segdir"`, `"%_segments"`, `"%_stat"`, and `"%_docsize"`, where `"%"` is replaced by the name of the FTS virtual table.

Answer (score 1):

There are virtual tables (like [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html)) that do store their data in the database.

But even if the virtual table module accesses external data, or just invents data, the actual virtual table definition itself (the `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE` statement) is still stored in the database, and the virtual table then is a persistent part of the database like any other table or view.

To see all the table definitions stored in your database, execute:

```
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';
```

For a table that is visible only in the current connection, and automatically deleted, you have to create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE MyTable(...);                    -- normal table
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.MyTable USING ...(...);  -- virtual table
```